# Codeigniter SMTP Error: Unable to send email using PHP SMTP

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I'm having trouble getting codeigniter's email library working with smtp.  Here are my email settings:

```
// Config File

$config['email_settings'] = array(
"protocol"  => "smtp",
"smtp_host" => "xxxxx",
"smtp_user" => "xxxxx",
"smtp_pass" => "xxxxx",
"smtp_port" => "587",
"crlf" => "\\r\\n",
"newline" => "\\r\\n",
"mailtype"  => "html"
);

// Code in controller used to initalize the mail library
$emailSettings = $this->config->item("email_settings");
$this->email->initialize($emailSettings);
```

I'm receiving the following message from the print_debugger:

```
220 xxxxx Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Mon, 11 Jan 2016 15:19:30 -0500

hello: 
The following SMTP error was encountered: 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
```

I've got it working with another smtp service but I need to use this different one.  Is it something with the server or am I messing up the settings?  From similar questions I've seen putting ssl:// in front of the smpt_host sometimes fixes it, but hasn't for me.

Comment: First off what are you using xampp, wamp etc.

Comment: ah sorry, using apache on linux

Comment: You may need to set your sendmail setting up on there also.

Comment: Why not just use the php mail function? I use it on Codeigniter.

Comment: Can you provide the code you're using to initialize and call the email library?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to send email using PHP mail(). Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method. codeigniter 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972179/unable-to-send-email-using-php-mail-your-server-might-not-be-configured-to-se)

Comment: Need to use smtp as mail() function usually sends to spam.  It works with another smtp service, so I know the server is able to send the mail.  Do you know if something on the actual mail server needs to be set up in order to send mail through php?

Comment: Hey @Leo - should be: $config['newline'] = "\r\n";